# Problem with bibtex

Tags: bibtex

I do not know what I am doing wrong but I have been stuck for about an hour now trying to get bibtex to work. Here is my latex code

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

hallo \cite{Saad:2003:IMS:829576}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{bibfile.bib}

\end{document}
```

and here is my bibtex file

```
@book{Saad:2003:IMS:829576,
 author = {Saad, Y.},
 title = {Iterative Methods for Sparse Linear Systems},
 year = {2003},
 isbn = {0898715342},
 edition = {2nd},
 publisher = {Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics},
 address = {Philadelphia, PA, USA},
}
```

Now it is not citing correctly, I do have the bibfile in the right directory. Something strange is happening, I got a citation to work earlier for a different book but not for this one. Now I deleted this other book from the bibfile.bib file but it is still showing up in my bibliography?!?! And like I said I cannot reference Saad's book. I do not know why. I am using Texmaker and everytime I run the bibtex file and then build the pdf but it does not work.

Here is an imgur link to what the output is. I hope someone can help

[image]

The book in the reference list is the one I got the citation working for.

Comment: Did you run BibTeX again?

Comment: Try to delete the LaTeX file (not .tex and .bib) to force the process.

Comment: I run BiBTeX like crazy :) Many times and then PDFLaTeX many times as well. It is very strange and highly frustrating the way that reference I do not want just keeps popping up.

Comment: Try `\bibliography{bibfile}` instead of `\bibliography{bibfile.bib}`.

Comment: Can you show us the contents of the `blg` file?

Comment: I am not getting a     blg file I am afraid... I guess it should be in the folder that holds the tex file and the bibfile

Comment: Also, I tried leaving out the .bib and I get exactly the same results... Thanks for suggestions so far by the way!

Comment: Well, I encounter no problems whatsoever as long as I use `\bibliography{bibfile}`.

Comment: It gives you the reference for Saad's book? Is it likely that Texmaker is the problem?

Comment: Windows has the tendency to hide file extensions, activate them in the folder options and open the blg-file with texmaker. It is possible, that you are giving the wrong argument to bibtex. It should be the basename of your main file.

Comment: I have file extensions turned on. In my other LaTeX folders I do see the .blg file but not in this folder. Sorry my knowledge of LaTeX in general may be somewhat lacking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer.)

I encounter no problems if I replace the instruction `\bibliography{bibfile.bib}` with `\bibliography{bibfile}`, i.e., if I omit the filename extension.

[image]

The bibliography file ('bibfile.bib'):

```
@book{Saad:2003:IMS:829576,
  author = {Saad, Y.},
  title = {Iterative Methods for Sparse Linear Systems},
  year = {2003},
  isbn = {0898715342},
  edition = {2nd},
  publisher = {Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics},
  address = {Philadelphia PA},
}
```

The main tex file (say, 'test.tex'):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\cite{Saad:2003:IMS:829576}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{bibfile}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Even copying that exact file does not work for me. Very weird. I tried using the online compiler of sharelatex and it does work. So I guess something is either wrong with my setup of TeXmaker or I should try a different compiler which I will do. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @Slugger - Did you run the compilation sequence LaTeX-BibTeX-LaTeX-LaTeX?

Comment: Ok so after running BibTeX and LaTeX a bunch of times it suddenly works. Thanks a lot for bearing with me :) !